# How to use ternary operator for the jsx using react?

Tags: reactjs

i have code like below

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        {active && (
            <Button 
                onClick={doSomething}
                disabled={someConditionTrue}
            > Click </Button>
        )}
    );
}
```

as seen from above code, the Button component is displayed when active is true.
now i want another Button compoennt within Tooltip to be displayed when active is true and  isStatus is true. and i dont want the other ButtonComponent without Tooltip to be displayed when this is Tooltip button displayed. so i rewrite above code like below,

```
return (
    {active && isStatus && (
        <Tooltip>
            <Button onClick={doSomething} disabled>
                Click
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
    )}
    {active && (
        <Button 
            onClick={doSomething}
            disabled={someConditionTrue}
        > Click </Button>
    )}
);
```

How can i rewrite above using ternary operator. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use a ternary? It doesn't seem necessary, nor is it the cleanest way to approach what you want to do.

Comment: Please try something like so: `return ({ active ? isStatus ? (<Tooltip>...</Tooltip>) : (<Button>....</Button>) : null });`. This will render `Tooltip` component when both `active` and `isStatus` are `'truthy'`. If `active` is `'truthy'`, but `isStatus` is `'falsy'`, it will render `Button` component. If `active` is `'falsy'` it will not render anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    {active && isStatus ? (
        <Tooltip>
            <Button onClick={doSomething} disabled>
                Click
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
    ): active && (
        <Button 
            onClick={doSomething}
            disabled={someConditionTrue}
        > Click </Button>
    )  }  
);
```